# Will there be a datadump of answers.onstartups.com?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, area-51, answers-onstartups

So, for those of you who don't know, [answers.onstartups.com](http://answers.onstartups.com) is no more. It is now a area 51 proposal.

So my question to the Stack Exchange team is this: Will there be a datadump of onstartups, including meta? There were things that are potentially relevant to the world at large. If so, is there an ETA on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a small lag between site closure and the CC-WIKI data dump.  It's available now for download [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business).