# Why was Startup StackExchange not approved as a fully fledged Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, area-51

[Startup Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business) had 4.9 questions per day during it's BETA period and was declined the opportunity to turn into a full StackExchange site, but the [Role Playing Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2208/role-playing-games) had only 3.4 questions per day and was approved.

All of the other metrics for both seem to have came up as **Excellent**.

Why was the role playing site approved, but the Startup site declined?

Comment: You also have to factor in the gut-check and quality of the posts, not just numbers.

Comment: @random I remember being on the startup SE website, I never noticed issues with quality, I guess if you were going to post answer, examples would be good!

Comment: @JMK: there were no long-term members, everyone kept drifting away.

Comment: Maybe all the members were acqui-hired by other SE sites

Comment: Fair enough, I guess I found it disappointing more than anything, partly because StackExchange was at one point a Startup itself and the Startup Exchange had some good advice on there itself for aspiring entrepreneur's!

Comment: Well, you can at least still grab the data dump: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211187/will-there-be-a-datadump-of-answers-onstartups-com

Comment: @random Yeah I have the Data dump, no issue navigating through that, would be happier if the site was still live though, I thought it was a good site!

Comment: Someone has [restarted the proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62811/startup-business).